# Ajax.BeginForm displaying partial view correctly in Chrome/FF but on new page in IE

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, view, partial, ajax.beginform

I've previously had a similar question answered which was resolved by downloading Ajax unobtrusive but a similar thing is now happening again after I've now published my website to IIS. Please see below code for an Ajax form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchResults","Export", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", HttpMethod="POST"}))
```

And the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(string searchString, string docType)
{
                return PartialView(db.ExportKofaxes.Where(x => x.DocumentNumber) 
}
```

In IE the partial view returned will open in new page but in both Chrome and FF it displays within the current view as intended. This is part of an MVC project, I copied across the project including the bin folder and scripts, the only thing making me think it's not an issue with any missing dll or script is the fact it works fine for both Chrome and FF but I'm seeing no Ajax dll's in my bin folder. When I copy across the project to IIS do I need to copy across the nuget packages folder also?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm extremely dumb, I have spent close on half a day working on why the hell it wouldn't work in IE and missed something stupid, all local sites were set to run in compatibility mode which I must have ticked at some point while testing something else. This was causing the partial view to open up in a new page.